# Set Jenkins global environment variables from a file

Tags: jenkins, configuration, global

Basically, I am running several jobs on Jenkins which have 2 different sets of email distribution lists, one for production, the other is for when we do the dry run. I want to be able to easily switch between the two. Currently, we have these as environment variables in the global properties section under 'Manage Jenkins'

[image]

The problem is that I have to change these between the dry run and production run (there is a email distro for each app). I want to put these into a properties file so I can easily switch. I thought I could do this, but it didn't work:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick test on my Linux environment and it works well with the [Envfile plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Envfile+Plugin).

Properties File Path:

```
/tmp/env.properties
```

File content:

```
TEST_STACKOVERFLOW = "my_value"
```

Build step:

```
echo $TEST_STACKOVERFLOW
```

Result:

```
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson8256628035734643761.sh
+ echo '"my_value"'
"my_value
```

Comment: This doesn't work for my situation.  I have jobs running on multiple nodes. I want to switch the properties at the master level, not the node or job level.

Comment: If you store the properties file on a network ressource, it will work.

Something like: \\my_file_server\release_engineering\my_file.properties